# if there is any social sharing plugins for Ionic 3 browser (PWA) platform

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic3 (PWA) browser platform, the social sharing plugin is not supported for browser platform. if any other plugins for social sharing for the browser platform let me know

Comment: Check this Repo: https://github.com/peterpeterparker/web-social-share

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this, im new to this